# mapview is crashing with many polylines when zooming or panning

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Can someboby help me to find out what is wrong?

i found sombody else with the same problem 2 years ago :(
See here:
[Exception when zooming with overlays on MKMapView: NSInvalidArgumentException NSSetM removeObject: object cannot be nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732344/exception-when-zooming-with-overlays-on-mkmapview-nsinvalidargumentexception-ns)

I dont add or remove something out of main thread.

The App runs sometimes 7h without problems.
With much zooming or panning i can force the app to fail.

Example Stack:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM removeObject:]: object cannot be nil'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8d66fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010960dac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a824ddc _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a84918c -[__NSSetM removeObject:] + 444
4   VectorKit                           0x0000000122808104 -[VKRasterOverlayTileSource removeOverlay:] + 89
5   VectorKit                           0x000000012244cb57 -[VKMapModel removeRasterOverlay:] + 68
6   MapKit                              0x000000010b92604c -[MKOverlayContainerView _removeDrawable:forOverlay:level:] + 517
7   MapKit                              0x000000010b9249f2 -[MKOverlayContainerView addAndRemoveOverlayViews] + 758
8   MapKit                              0x000000010b8c821d -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:] + 181
9   MapKit                              0x000000010b8cd4a2 -[MKMapView mapLayer:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 67
10  VectorKit                           0x0000000122405e54 -[VKMapView map:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 122
11  VectorKit                           0x00000001224804bf -[VKMapCameraController rotateToPitch:withPoint:preserveAltitude:animated:exaggerate:] + 1480
12  VectorKit                           0x0000000122481b44 -[VKMapCameraController snapMapIfNecessary:] + 300
13  MapKit                              0x000000010b92604c -[MKOverlayContainerView _removeDrawable:forOverlay:level:] + 517
14  MapKit                              0x000000010b9249f2 -[MKOverlayContainerView addAndRemoveOverlayViews] + 758
15  MapKit                              0x000000010b8c821d -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:] + 181
16  MapKit                              0x000000010b8cd4a2 -[MKMapView mapLayer:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 67
17  VectorKit                           0x0000000122405e54 -[VKMapView map:didChangeRegionAnimated:] + 122
18  VectorKit                           0x000000012248419b -[VKMapCameraController _animateToPosition:pitch:yaw:duration:timingCurve:completion:] + 1797
19  VectorKit                           0x000000012248468b -[VKMapCameraController setCenterCoordinate:altitude:yaw:pitch:duration:animationStyle:timingCurve:completion:] + 331
20  VectorKit                           0x0000000122401391 -[VKMapView setCenterCoordinate:altitude:yaw:pitch:duration:timingCurve:completion:] + 411
21  MapKit                              0x000000010b904bc4 -[MKMapView(MKCamera) _updateFromCamera:duration:timing:completionHandler:] + 507
22  MapKit                              0x000000010b904836 -[MKMapView(MKCamera) _setCamera:duration:timing:completionHandler:] + 222
23  MapKit                              0x000000010b90468f -[MKMapView(MKCamera) _setCamera:animated:] + 277
24  MapKit                              0x000000010b8daa0c -[MKMapView setCamera:animated:] + 231
25  VW-R-CLUB Member APP                0x00000001034575cf $s20VW_R_CLUB_Member_APP17MapViewControllerC24headingDisplayLinkUpdate33_A3F09DE885E5AFD820CE3A36D7605AB9LL4linkySo09CADisplayJ0C_tF + 2095
26  VW-R-CLUB Member APP                0x0000000103457b7c $s20VW_R_CLUB_Member_APP17MapViewControllerC24headingDisplayLinkUpdate33_A3F09DE885E5AFD820CE3A36D7605AB9LL4linkySo09CADisplayJ0C_tFTo + 60
27  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106b50d97 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 663
28  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106c1f4a2 _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 297
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a812096 __CFMachPortPerform + 150
30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a83e419 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a83da7b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 459
32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a83800a __CFRunLoopRun + 2490
33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a837302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
34  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001107e72fe GSEventRunModal + 65
35  UIKitCore                           0x00000001145fbba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
36  VW-R-CLUB Member APP                0x000000010379ebeb main + 75
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d151541 start + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Do you have 3D View enabled for your MapView? I had a very similar stack trace when I was using 3D View with overlays. I don't think they play well together. Overlay objects can only have 2D coordinates. My crash occurred when panning quickly while viewing the ground around a 45 degree angle.

Comment: @user2129643 Yes is do.